# How do I center the title when exporting org file to HTML

Tags: html

```
#+TITLE: Hello World
#+AUTHOR: A. U. Thor
#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
#+HTML_DOCTYPE: html5
```

currently gives me this as output where the title is centered to the left.

[image]

Comment: In your style.css add `.title {text-align: center;}`. Classes used when exporting are documented in the org manual: https://orgmode.org/manual/CSS-support.html. This might of course not work if there is something else in your style.css that overwrites this. Can post as answer if this is what you needed. It's also possible to modify CSS inside the org file if that is what you need.

Comment: Thank you that worked!

Comment: Yes please do leave as an answer.

Comment: Please consider accepting @Hubisan's answer if it does solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

In your `style.css` add `.title {text-align: center;}` to center the document title in the exported html file.

Classes used when exporting are documented in the org manual: [CSS-Support](https://orgmode.org/manual/CSS-support.html). Or inspect the generated html file to see what element and class are used. For the document title this will be the following:

```html
<h1 class="title">Hello World</h1>
```

---

It's also possible to **modify the CSS style definitions inside the org file directly** as follows:

1. Add a #+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA to the top section in your org file. This will be appended to the HTML document’s head:

   ```
   #+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <style type="text/css">.title {text-align: center;}</style>
   ```
2. Use inline html to include raw html:

   ```
   @@html:<style type="text/css">.title {width: 270px;}</style>@@
   ```
3. Use a html export code block to include raw html:

   ```
   #+begin_export html
     <style type="text/css">.title {width: 270px;}</style>
   #+end_export
   ```